# How to configure windows client proxy in WSL2

Tags: proxy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I have a proxy client running on windows which provides a socks5 proxy. This client has been set to listening `127.0.0.1:9050` .I want to use it in WSL2 **Kali Linux terminal**.How can I ??

Exactly what I am trying to do is ,to rotate IP's  in kali Linux terminal **WSL2** via  windows client proxy application. The proxy application itself changes/rotate proxy
frequently no need of other application in the WSL2.

So the only need is How can I connect it in WSL.

The proxy client supports `socksv5` so I have to set the WSL to socksv5 proxy.

**TIA!**